# Animate a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I've a question, is it possible to animate a link (or a page change) with jQuery. I think at something like, that someone clicks on the link and the page slides to the left side an the other one comes from the right side. Is that possible ?

Github uses something like that but I don't know how.

I hope that you understand my question, if not - ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Instead, you can load the content into the current page using AJAX, and animate it in.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. But isn't there any plugin which does that?

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/